# Eliminate subquery in the FROM clause

Tags: sql, hql

The tagging table has 3 columns: *id* (the primary key), *tag*, and *resource*.

I want to select the tags that are associated with at least 3 resources. A resource can be associated several times with the same tag, so a single *GROUP BY* is not enough.

My current SQL query is the following:

```
SELECT tag FROM
(SELECT resource, tag FROM tagging GROUP BY resource, tag) AS tagging
GROUP BY tag HAVING count(*) > 2;
```

I need to convert this request in HQL, and HQL does not accept subqueries inside the *FROM* clause.

Is there a (fast) way to do the same thing without using a subquery, or with a subquery in the *WHERE* clause?

Thank you

Comment: Your text says "at least 2" your current query is `> 2`. Which is it?

Comment: You are right, I corrected it, though it does not really matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find tags that are associated with more than 2 different resources you can use

```
SELECT tag
FROM   tagging
GROUP  BY tag
HAVING count(DISTINCT resource) > 2;
```

Comment: Thank you, that is great. What if I want to count only the resources which have a least 3 occurences of the tag (by adding HAVING count(*) > 2 in the subquery)?